# ¿ Cómo seleccionar el elemento de navegación activo al hacer scroll con Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un microsite con [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), donde básicamente tengo una sola página con varias secciones, y un `navbar` donde tengo un enlace a cada sección. El código es el siguiente

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-alternative navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegación</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#sect1">Seccion 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sect2">Seccion 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sect3">Seccion 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contactar</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que necesito es que a medida que el visitante va haciendo scroll y adentrandose en las diferentes secciones, el elemento de navegación marcado con la clase `active` cambie según la sección en que se encuentra el usuario.

Un ejemplo de este comportamiento puede verse [Aquí](https://www.docker.com/what-docker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar debes de agregar un escuchador para el evento scroll del documento:

```
$(window).on('scroll', () => {
   ...
});
```

Lo siguiente es verificar si la posición del scrollbar hace match con las secciones previamente definidas. Por ejemplo, si tenemos las siguientes secciones:

```
const sections = ['#home', '#services', '#about', '#contact'];
```

Cada vez que se haga scroll debemos ver si nos encontramos en ellas:

```
sections.forEach((section) => {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() => $(section).position().top) {
    if (!$(`navbar a[href="${section}"]`).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.navbar a').removeClass('active'); // eliminamos la clase active del que la tenga
      $(`navbar a[href="${section}"]`).addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

El código anterior verifica si el scrollbar se encuentra en la posición de cada section que tenemos en el array. En caso sea así, miramos si `.navbar[href="<id del section>"]` tiene la clase `active`, si no la tiene se la agregamos.

**Nota:** el código lo he escrito usando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) dado que estás usando bootstrap.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Tu respuesta me ayudó a resolver el problema. Algunas observaciones: Necesito la mayor compatibilidad posible en javascript, por lo tanto tuve que cambiar las expresiones lambda con funciones anonimas, otra cosa el operador de comparacion `>=` lo pones como `=>` lo cual no funciona, por ultimo, tambien reemplace los operadores comilla invertida por strings normales (por compatibilidad). Ah se me olvidaba, top no es una funcion. Crees que puedas realizar esos cambios en la respuesta para de esa manera aceptarla. Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @AbrahamTS Gracias por la observación de `top`. Me alegro te haya servido.

Answer (score 1):

Basandome en la [respuesta de Guz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94604/c%c3%b3mo-seleccionar-el-elemento-de-navegaci%c3%b3n-activo-al-hacer-scroll-con-bootstra/94606#answer-94606), as fue como lo hice finalmente:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
       var sections = ['#top', '#prod1', '#prod2', '#prod3', '#contact'];
       sections.forEach(function(section) {
          var sectionObj = $(section);
          if (!sectionObj.length)
            // No se encontro un elemento con ese id
            return;

          if ($(window).scrollTop() + 100 >= sectionObj.position().top) {
            if (!$('.navbar .nav a[data-target="'+ section +'"]').hasClass('active')) {
              $('.navbar a').removeClass('active'); // eliminamos la clase active del que la tenga
              $('.navbar .nav a[data-target="'+ section +'"]').addClass('active');
            }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

El uso de las comillas invertidas y las expresiones flecha son un [elemento nuevo del estandar **ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) y por eso solo son compatibles versiones modernas de los navegadores.

Quiero soportar la mayor cantidad posible de navegadores (dado que la elección del navegador depende del cliente). Por tal motivo he cambiado las funciones flecha de la **respuesta de Guz** por funciones anonimas de Javascript y también las comillas invertidas.

---

#### Otra forma de hacerlo :

También se puede usar el módulo [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#scrollspy) de **Bootstrap** añadiendo el atributo `data-spy="scroll"` al `<body>` y el atributo `data-target` con la clase o atributo padre de cualquier componente `.nav`, en mi caso `data-target=".navbar"`.